# Formula to get total combination possibilities

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

- There are `Num` guys
- The sum of their ages is `Tot`
- The `Age` of every one of them is `Min <= Age <= Max`

I want to create a formula for a program to calculate the total number of possibilities

Any ideas/links that point me to the right direction are appreciated

Comment: What you are asking seems to be about [partitions of a number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), and more specifically partitions of `Tot - Num*Min` with at most `Num` summands and no summand greater than `Max - Min`.  Formulas for this kind of thing can be pretty hard to program, but setting up a loop to run through all of the possibilities and count them is pretty straightforward.  See Henry Bottomley's online [partition calculators](http://www.btinternet.com/~se16/js/partitionstest.htm) for some ideas.

Comment: @BrettFrankel sorry, I wasn't familiarized with any tags, but after some time reading I think I found some that fit ^^

Comment: @ajax333221: Those tags were inapproriate -- I replaced them with [tag:combinatorics].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map this to the problem of [balls in bins with limited capacity](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm) by subtracting $\text{Num}\cdot\text{Min}$ from $\text{Tot}$ and then distributing the remainder into $\text{Num}$ bins with equal capacity $\text{Max}-\text{Min}$. The above page gives a formula for the case of equal capacities at the very end, which can be derived using the [inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) by considering the number of bins filled to capacity.